# C# console quick edit -- clear selection in progress

Tags: c#, windows, console

What windows api can I use to clear a console selection (eg made using the mouse in quick edit mode) that is in progress?

I tried programmatically disabling Quick Edit mode via SetConsoleMode() but that does not clear a selection that is in progress.

Comment: I would have tried to detect that there is a selection active with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsoleselectioninfo and then sent the Escape with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/writeconsoleinput